# Number or train and validation samples is not shown as a return of model.fit

Tags: tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

I noticed while editing an old notebook that model.fit (in keras) where model = Sequential() always returns the number of train and validation samples (for example: `Train on 2508 samples, validate on 250 samples`) just before showing the epoch progress. Yet I don't see it when I ran the training process again and  I immediately see the epoch progress. (Note: verbose is set to 1).

I even checked keras.io/guides all outputs for Sequential.fit() methods don't return this line as well.

Did that happen due to a new update or do I need to add a certain parameter?

Comment: Is your issue resolved now? Else, can you share standalone code to replicate your issue, so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```